# Is it OK to run NM-B cable from outlet behind TV to surge protector?

Tags: electrical, television

I already know that I can't run a TV's actual power cord behind the wall to a surge protector.

Here's what I'm thinking about doing instead.  Mount a recessed outlet behind the TV, run the cable behind the wall from that outlet down to a [recessed multimedia wall plate](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Cooper-Wiring-Devices-1-Gang-Recessed-Multimedia-Cable-Wall-Plate-White-35M1W-SP-L/203492457) where it would come out and be terminated with a 15 amp plug and then plugged into a UPS surge protector.

Is this OK and if not what could be done that would allow the TV to be plugged into surge protector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Why you shouldn't use NM cable

NM-B cable (Romex®) is not designed to be used as a flexible cord, and must be properly secured and supported.  It's also not rated for use where it may be exposed to physical damage.

Flexible cords have thicker jackets, which are designed to hold up to a bit more abuse.  They also contain stranded wires, which hold up to movement much better than solid core wire.

If you were to use NM-B cable in this way, there's a few potential problems.

#### Abuse

The exposed bit of cable could be damaged, exposing the conductors. This could be a shock, and/or arc-fault hazard.

#### Movement

Repeated movement of the cable, could cause damage to the core of the wires. This damage could lead to increased resistance, which could be a fire hazard. Ultimately the movement could lead to the conductors breaking, which could pose an arc-fault hazard.

---

## Alternative solutions

Instead you could go with a product like this [Recessed Pro Power Kit w/Straight Blade Inlet](http://www.monoprice.com/product?c_id=104&cp_id=10425&cs_id=1042513&p_id=4652&seq=1&format=2).  The inlet at the bottom of the wall, gives you a place to connect a power cord.  The lower inlet is then connected to the upper outlet, using proper cable (e.g  nonmetallic sheathed cable NM-B).

[image: Recessed Pro Power Kit w/Straight Blade Inlet]

This is a much better, safer, and cleaner installation.

You'll also find that [surge suppressor receptacles](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ProductDetail.jsp?partnumber=T5280-W&section=39994&minisite=10251) are available, though may not offer the same level of protection as a standalone device.

[image: surge suppressor receptacles]

`Products shown are for demonstration purposes only, I do not recommend or endorse these specific product.`

Comment: I like testers way better we must have been typing at the same time

Comment: Would you mind commenting as to why this is safer?  Is the primary reason that the recessed wall plate I referenced isn't rated to have romex going through it or more because the above outlet is connected to a wire that is dangling?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor I've updated my answer.

Comment: One last question, are you aware of whether or not that male plug outlet is available outside of a kit like this?  I tried to find one and came up empty so I'm guessing it isn't but maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Inlets are available at electrical suplly shops, online, or and hardware and big box stores. Nice looking units that you'd want in your house, are likely only available as part of a kit, or from places that deal specifically in AV equipment (e.g. monoprice, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The box you linked to is not listed for power. I understand what you are trying to do and it "sounds good".
If you wired your Romex to a box below then came out with less than 6’ of flexible conduit (stranded wire 14 awg like THHN) to a plug that plugs into your UPS would work.
I have seen some boxes with feeds similar to this with a cord grip and SO (extension cord material) with a plug but this is not legal where the flexible conduit is.